# Connect to Multiple Databases on Different Servers

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine

I have been using Symfony with Doctrine for some time, and up until now was able to configure Doctrine to connect to several databases on the same server (IP), through the config.yml.

But now I have a different scenario.

I am working on a case, that has multiple projects running on different IP adresses. I can connect with the database that runs locally on the machine that also hosts the main application, but now I need to connect to another database that's hosted on another server. So, to lay out this case:

- Server Alpha. IP: 193.15.15.15, database name: "Foo"
- Server Beta. IP: 193.15.15.16, database name: "Bar"

I have defined the user and password for each of these databases in my parameters.yml, so that is no biggie. I just would like to know if it's possible to connect to the (locally hosted) database on server Beta, while the application is on server Alpha.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should configure multiple entity managers and connections 
On the file config.yml :

```
doctrine:
     dbal:
         default_connection: default
         connections:
            default:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     '193.15.15.15'
                port:     '%port_parameter_for_foo%'
                dbname:   'Foo'
                user:     '%user_parameter_for_foo%'
                password: '%pass_parameter_for_foo%'
                charset:  UTF8
            customer:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     '193.15.15.16'
                port:     '%port_parameter_for_bar%'
                dbname:   'Bar'
                user:     '%user_parameter_for_bar%'
                password: '%pass_parameter_for_bar%'
                charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    BundleOnAlpha:  ~
            customer:
                connection: beta
                mappings:
                    BundleOnBeta: ~
```

The doc is more complete: 
https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

Comment: This is what I have at the moment for a few databases that are in different bundles. But they are on the same server. The doc says nothing about connecting to a database on a different server.

Comment: You can set a different "host" value for each connection, just set it to the IP of the server where the database runs. On that server, you have to make sure that connections to the mysql server from other hosts are allowed, by default it will listen to localhost only.